# Upgrading to Neo4j to 2.2 from 2.1.6 on OSX

Tags: neo4j

having read the documentation...

http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/deployment-upgrading.html#automatic-upgrade

It states-

> Install Neo4j 2.2.0-RC01, and set it up to use the same database store directory (typically data/graph.db).

But how exactly do I **Install** it? I think I just used **brew** to install it in the first place but

`brew install neo4j`

results in

`Warning: neo4j-2.1.6 already installed`

I would greatly appreciate a simple, noobs guide to upgrading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 2.2.0-RC01 is a pre-release it isn't available via homebrew (homebrew doesn't let you pick a version to install.  It's always the latest stable release of the package).

Go to neo4j.com and follow the download link for 2.2.0-RC01. Download it and unpack the tarball with `tar xvfz neo4j-community-XXX.tar.gz`. Once uncompressed you should:

- Copy over your store from 2.1.6 (data/graph.db directory) to the unpacked directory structure
- Set `allow_store_upgrade=true` in `conf/neo4j.properties`
- Change the `org.neo4j.server.webserver.port` and `org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port` properties so as not to conflict with your 2.1.6 installation
- Start Neo4j with `bin/neo4j start`.

Notes:

- I would not overwrite the installation via homebrew to avoid issues with it later on
- Make sure the Neo4j 2.1.6 instance is stopped before copying over the store files

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer, Brian! ;)

Comment: Kick ass, thanks for your help guys. I really needed those curved relationship that show in the GUI that don't overlap when there's one or more. I hope that makes sense. You've made my day. Thanks kindly.